# Как реализовать такой же слайдер?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

Как реализовать данный слайдер. Вроде сделан на slick.

Как сделать, чтобы центральное изображение было больше остальных и как сделать такие точки с надписями, которые соответственно реагируют на слайдер. Может есть готовые библиотеки с такими объектами.
Спасибо.

[image: Slider]

Comment: А фреймворки типа uikit на что?

Comment: Ничего похожего я не увидел.

Comment: откройте DevTools и наведите на центральный блок - увидите - `class="slick-center"` вот его стилизуйте в cs

Comment: Макс, спасибо, такие мысли были, пока стоит остро вопрос точек (меню).

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/hu9esd6j/1/  допилить сможешь ?

Comment: Спасибо. В другом посте поставил +